# Replace several instances of wildcard with an array of strings in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string with several instances of a single wildcard character:

```
An $X a $X keeps the $X away.
```

and an array with replace terms:

```
["apple","day","doctor"]
```

I want to replace the first wildcard with the first array value, the second wildcard with the second array value etc, giving:

```
An apple a day keeps the doctor away.
```

I'm sorry if this has been asked elsewhere, but I can't find any examples with a *single* search and *multiple* replaces, only multiple searches for multiple replaces, but the wildcards are not numbered so this wouldn't be suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[(s)printf](http://php.net/sprintf) should do what you're asking for.

Comment: How do I specify a custom wildcard character?  And is there a way I can use it without explicity stating every item in the array?  I'd like to be able to write something like sprintf($content, $wildcard, $array), rather than sprintf($content, $array[0], $array[1], etc) since my array might contain a hundred or so items...

Comment: @user3640967 Scrub that, see @casimir's comment in the other answer. Give `vsprintf` a try for that usecase.

Comment: This is not a generous, insightful answer.  See the duplicate and the related pages on the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of `sprintf()` and `list()`:

```
$sentence = "An %s a %s keeps the %s away.";
$array = ["apple","day","doctor"];
echo sprintf($sentence , $array[0], $array[1], $array[2]);

// or not a single wildcard.
$array = ["apple","day","doctor"];
list($apple, $day, $doctor) = $array ;
echo "An $apple a $day keeps the $doctor away.";
```

Comment: Note that you can use `vsprintf` with an array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php